# Find items in one Excel column that are not in another column and put them in a new column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

***What I want to do***

Find Items in one column (`ColA`) that are not in another column (`ColB`). What to do when I want the result not being highlighted, but have it in another column (`ColC`) without blank rows.

**Example**

```
ColA - ColB - ColC    
1 - 1 - 4
3 - 2 - 8
10 - 3 - 10
4 - 5 - "" 
5 - 7 - ""    
8 - 6 - ""
9 - 9 - ""
```

**What did I try yet**

Until now I succeeded to have the following result. I do this with the following formula in column C:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A2;B$2:F$300;0);"")<>"";"";A2)
```

Result:

```
ColA - ColB - ColC
1 - 1 - ""
3 - 2 - ""
10 - 3 - 10
4 - 5 - 4     
5 - 7 - "" 
8 - 6 - 8
9 - 9 - ""
```

**But I want to avoid the blank cells in Col C.**

I tried the formula I found in one of the answers on this site:

```
IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$1999,MATCH(0,IFERROR(MATCH($A$2:$A$1999,$B$2:$B$399,0),COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,$A$2:$A$1999)),0)),"")
```

… but this does not work. Maybe I adapt this formula in a wrong way...?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use an [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx). Assuming your data in ColA and ColB is in rows 1 to 10, select rows 1 to 10 of ColC, then input the following formula in the formula bar:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1:A10,B1:B10,0)),A1:A10,""),ROW()),"")
```

Store it as an array formula by pressing *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* (on Windows) / *Cmd+Shift+Enter* (on OS X) – if you did it right, the formula will display enclosed in braces (`{}`) and look identical in all cells. As applied to your example data, this is what you get:

[image: screenshot of the formula used on the posted example]

Note there are a few gotchas when working with array formulas (they can only be edited by editing the whole range, cannot be shrunk, can only be expanded by manually editing the formula … see the article I linked to for some details, section “Rules for entering and changing array formulas”).

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation, but it does not work. What am I doing wrong ? 

First I had to adapt the formula, since the ',' is not accepted, it should be a ';' on my computer. So it became : =IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1:A10;B1:B10;0));A1:A10;"");ROW());"")   

Then I selected the cells C1->C10 and I pasted the formula in it + afterwards ctrl+shift+enter.
The result in all cells=0
The formula in C2 =IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2:A11;B2:B11;0));A2:A11;"");ROW());"")

So no {} in or around the formula.

Can it be that Ctrl+Shift+Enter should be something else on my computer?

Comment: No, just a minor misunderstanding as to execution to clear up :). To get the formula to work, delete the formulas in C1:C10, select the cells again (as one selection area), then insert the formula **into the formula input bar** (that is the field above the table headers where you can call up the formula assistant) – **do not** paste directly into the sheet! Then hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter and you should be good to go.